# Authenticode or other code signing for Mac and Linux

Tags: c, linux, macos, signing

Is there anything similar to Authenticode for Mac and Linux?

If yes, could anyone point to a sample snippet, preferably in C, on how to check that the signature match?

Thank you

EDIT: There is one possible answer to the Mac part in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815506/how-to-obtain-codesigned-application-certificate-info) but I don't know whether this can be done in plain C.

Comment: I don't know whether there exists an implementation of Authenticode for Mac/Linux, but hashes and GPG signatures are common on Linux. You may wish to include more details so that others can suggest alternatives that accomplish your goal. Details such as: one app or more, how multiple apps communicate, etc.

Comment: I retreated my answer, I can't help you with this (not my specialization nor interest). I'm sorry.

Comment: This question should probably be split into two questions: one for Mac OS X, another one for Linux. Also, consider enumerating your requirements for a code signing solution.

Comment: @Bavarious, although your comment about "splitting into two questions" may have been relevant in 2011, since then, package managers such as Homebrew for Mac have brought forward many Linux tools, such as http://brewformulas.org/Osslsigncode, which makes the question quite relevant as a single, encompassing question and thus an encompassing, single solution.  For example, Travis-CI (continuous integration) has Homebrew installed by default, making the software installation (and thus authenticode signing) scriptable and consistent across both OS X as well as Linux.

Answer (score 3):

The standard way of authenticating code running on a Linux system is to validate the binaries once while installing the package rather than every time they are run. The package (e.g. RPM) contains a cryptographic signature that must match the contents of the files or the installer will refuse to install. Standard UNIX permissions prevent ordinary users from modifying those files on disk afterward. Periodically, the checksums of the files on disk can be compared with what they should be (using RPM or TripWire or something similar) just in case they were able to be modified or become corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

On the Mac you can sign your binaries with the same Authenticode cert you would use on Windows (at least we do this and it works fine).

You need to import the certificate (including the private key) into your keychain and then use Xcode or [codesign](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/codesign.1.html) to sign the binary.