# Digitally signing an executable, trusting its requests on the server

Tags: security, certificate, digital-signature, code-signing, assembly-signing

I'm building a cross-platform app that will communicate with the server. Security is very important.

Is there a scheme that will allow me to "trust" that the executable is genuine and hasn't been tampered with and that the requests are indeed coming from my signed executable and not an impersonator? Seems like the traditional man-in-the-middle attack. How can I prevent it?

I understand that I can sign an executable with a trusted CA under Windows. This ensures that the executable hasn't been tampered with on the user's machine. However, a targeted virus can still replace the executable (as opposed to modifying it) with an impersonator and Windows won't complain.

Can, then, my genuine executable sign the requests it is making to the server and can I validate these requests on the server? The naive solution is to embed a "private certificate" in the signed executable. However, I suspect that it's possible to extract this private certificate even from a signed executable.

Finally, are there executable signing mechanisms in OSX and Linux?

Comment: The 3 most important rules of client/server security are (1) Never trust the client. (2) Never trust the client. (3) Never trust the client.

Answer (score 1):

For code signing on Mac there are some reference in StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951310/authenticode-or-other-code-signing-for-mac-and-linux) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815506/how-to-obtain-codesigned-application-certificate-info). I've seen different things for Linux like [signelf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/signelf/), [bsign](ftp://ftp.buici.com/pub/bsign) (used by [digsig](http://disec.sourceforge.net/)), [elfsign](http://www.hick.org/code/skape/elfsign/).

As mentioned by Nickolay O., code signing will not do anything against decompilation. Code signing doesn't prevent man-in-the-middle and it's not a solution to demonstrate to a server that the client hasn't been tampered with.

Comment: Appreciate the links. Are you aware of any approach that can guarantee that the client hasn't been tempered with?

Answer (score 0):

Signing executables has meaning only for OS - to let it know, that executable is a good one.
If somebody can decompile your application, than you cannot be sure in any way that request was sent by the valid executable.