# iOS - Programmatically check if the app is authentic

Tags: ios, codesign, integrity

How do i check if my iOS app is code-signed with my certificate? or any other way by which i can determine that the app is original?
I've seen that its possible in case of Mac, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815506/how-to-obtain-codesigned-application-certificate-info). 
Please share info if you have come across a solution for iOS.

Comment: Did you find a way ?